# How does Newton's First Law show the existence of inertial reference frames?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, definition, inertia

Newton merely stated the law of inertia as:

> An object at rest stays at rest, and an object in motion stays in motion with the same speed and in the same direction unless acted upon by an unbalanced force.

How does it prove the existence of inertial frames? I see no mention of it in the original law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newton's first law doesn't "prove" the existence of inertial frames; it *defines* inertial frames.

An inertial frame is one in which Newton's first law holds.

Comment: but why didn't he(newton) define it in the law. did he *assume* that the law holds in inertial frames only?